# In Java, is there a way load class implementing interface that does not exist?

Tags: java, interface, classloader, .class-file

I've seen Java doing a lot of magic, but is it possible to do this:

At runtime, using (for example) `ClassLoader.defineClass`, load class `A` that implements interface `B`. The interface `B` does not actually exist in class path. Java will throw an exception (`ClassNotFoundException` IIRC) and the class won't be loaded. All other parts of class `A` are OK, and I know for a fact that no other part of program will be using interface `B`. So, what I want to do is to make the interpreter *ignore* the missing interface definition and load a class that is completely the same as `A` except that is does not implement the interface `B`.

Is this possible? It of course could be achieved by catching the exception and manually editing the binary data of class `A`, then loading it again. Or by creating a dummy empty interface named B at runtime by manually constructing the B.class file and then loading it. But it seems a bit messy, so my question is, does Java provide any convenient ways to do this?

If not, I guess, I'll try implementing one of those two methods, but I still want to hear an opinion.

I'm doing this to provide a convenient way for two different code bases to interact with each other if they both are loaded, and to just work fine if only one of them is.

Comment: You're trying to do a messy job, so all solutions will be messy. I don't think there's a way around "messy" for this particular approach.

Comment: Those must be wicked code bases, if you have to tweak at that level to make them interact / work independently...

Comment: ... what about loading the interface first? Just a thought...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any non-messy solutions to this that work similarly to what you're describing. It all boils down to a custom `ClassLoader`. Custom `ClassLoaders` are kind-of hard to begin with and if they have very specific semantics like this, then they become *very* ugly.

Not to mention the types of problems that you'll run into if your code suddenly *doesn't* run inside that `ClassLoader`.

I think the *sane* solution to this is to produce a `mylibrary.jar` and a `mylibrary-noB.jar` (or even more explicit: `mylibrary-withB.jar` and `mylibrary-noB.jar`) and let the users just select which one they want.

Comment: I'm making a plugin system for a computer game. Imagine three separate plugins provide some optional functionality through interfaces B, C and D. And the plugin A adds a lot of stuff that can possibly interact with plugins B, C and D through those interfaces. Your way, the author of A will have to provide 8 versions of his plugin. My way, he just has to write his code and make .jar out of it. Of course there are ways to allow interaction if a different way, but I see this one as the most convenient for the ones who will be writing those plugins.

Comment: @AUTOMATIC: the problem with your solution is that it only covers **implementing** interfaces from libraries that don't exist at runtime. But what if that class actually wants to **handle** objects of that type? If plugin A wants to optionally interact with plugin B, then it is *probably* not sufficient to implement some of Bs interfaces, you might need to call into it as well. In that case the common solution for plugin-based architectures is to provide a A.B sub-plugin that adds the B-based features of A and depends on both A and B. If B is not given, then only the A base-plugin is loaded.

Comment: Also: even if the developer needs only 1 jar instead of 8, he'll have to **test** 8 different scenarios, because even if only a single `jar` is produced: it *will* behave differently in any of those scenarios. So having to produce only 1 jar doesn't really make things significantly easier.

Comment: In some cases, you're right, something more than just implementing interfaces is necessary. But I still want to provide a more simple alternative (from user's standpoint) when it's not. And about testing -- no one is going to test all 8 variations every time time he releases new version, especially after making unrelated changes.

Comment: I still think that any byte-code manipulation approaches will be highly complex, hard to understand, hard to maintain and fairly non-intuitive. And the possible gain is relatively small, because it only covers a small subset of all possible uses.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly common to include a second jar with the additional interfaces. The second jar can be included if needed and dropped if not. If its added to the end of the class path, this will happen implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the code in the classpath entry where interface `B` is defined has to use the same class as the code in the classpath entry where class `A` is defined. So defining a dummy interface will not work.

In Java you can dynamically implement an interface with a Proxy:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

So at a later point in time, when your interface `A` is available, you can get it by reflection and create Proxy that implements its methods. The following example shows this with the `java.lang.Runnable` interface as interface `A`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class ProxyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class interfaceClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Runnable");

        Object implementingRunnable = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                    ProxyTest.class.getClassLoader(),
                    new Class[] {interfaceClass},
                    new MyInvocationHandler()
        );

        ((Runnable)implementingRunnable).run();


    }

    static class MyInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args)
                throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("called " + m);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course at some point you have to actually cast the proxy to the interface `A`. You would have to do this in a class that is defined in the same class path entry as the interface.